# Suppose $\dim V >\dim W$. Then no linear map from $V$ to $W$ is injective

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I know this is fairly trivial but how is $\dim\operatorname{range}T > \dim W$? Basically, can someone explain the first inequality (as well as the second)?

> $\mathbf{3.23}$ **A map to a smaller dimensional space is not injective**
> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces such that $\dim V>\dim W$. Then no linear map from $V$ to $W$ is injective.

*Proof*$~$ Let $T\in\mathcal L(V,W)$. Then

\begin{align*}
\dim\operatorname{null} T 
&= \dim V-\dim\operatorname{range} T
\\
&\ge\dim V-\dim W
\\
&>0\,,
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality comes from the fact that$$\operatorname{range}T\subset W\implies\dim\operatorname{range}T\leqslant\dim W$$and the second one from the fact that we are assuming that $\dim V>\dim W$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The second inequality is the hypothesis. Note that the first inequality stems from $\dim\,\mathrm{range}\,T \leq \dim{W}$. This inequality holds because the range of $T$ is a subspace of $W$.

Comment: Thank you very much!